# Maintaining jobs history in apscheduler

Tags: python, scheduler, apscheduler

I am using apscheduler to schedule my scrapy spiders. I need to maintain history of all the jobs executed. I am using mongodb jobstore. By default, apscheduler maintains only the details of the currently running job. How can I make it to store all instances of a particular job?

Answer (score 2):

If you want such extra functionality, add the appropriate event listeners to the scheduler to detect the adding and any modifications to a job. In the event listener, get the job from the scheduler and store it wherever you want. They are serializable btw.